# Links y Divs en html

Tags: html5, div

Estoy haciendo una pagina en html, y estoy intentando hacer que desde un div indice, se haga click en un enlace, que haga cambiar el contenido de otro div en el que por defecto esta una pagina con un titulo.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<title>
Libro Fantas&iacute;a
</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="indice">
    <h2>
    &Iacute;ndice
    </h2>
<hr>
<ol type="1" id="ol1">
    <li>
    Presentaci&oacute;n
    </li>
    <li>
    Razas
        <ul id="ul1">
            <li>
            <a href="Razas/Humanos.html">Humanos</a> 
            </li>
            <li>
            <a href="Razas/Elfos.html">Elfos</a>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a href="Razas/Ogros.html">Ogros</a>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a href="Razas/Enanos.html">Enanos</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
    Zonas
        <ul id="ul2">
            <li>
            <a href="Zonas/Rios.html">R&iacute;os</a>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a href="Zonas/Bosques.html">Bosques</a>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a href="Zonas/Ciudades.html">Ciudades</a>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a href="Zonas/Monta%C3%B1as.html">Montañas</a>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a href="Zonas/Sub.html">Reino Submarino</a>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a href="Zonas/Cielo.html">Reino del Cielo</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="Tablas.html">Estad&iacute;sticas y Tablas</a>
    </li>
</ol>
</div>
<div id="contenido">
    <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="Pagina%20titulo.html"></iframe>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Creo que no existe nada de esto en CSS. Creo que lo más óptimo sería usar Javascript para este caso.

Comment: Es que precisamente es eso, que no sabemos como hacerlo, nisiquiera que intentar

Comment: Con ese código que tienes lo que puedes hacer es con JavaScript o jQuery capturar el valor del `href` del enlace y pasarlo al `src` del `iframe`

Answer (score 2):

Si lo que quieres hacer es que los enlaces se abran en el `iframe`, lo que tienes que haces es sencillo:

1. Ponerle un atributo `name` al `iframe`
2. Ponerle un atributo `target` a los enlaces, cuyo contenido será el `name` del `iframe`

Si los enlaces tienen en el atributo `target` un nombre de `iframe` válido, entonces se abrirán en ese `iframe` en particular en lugar de en la ventana padre.

En tu caso particular se vería así:

```
<div id="indice">
  <h2>
    &Iacute;ndice
  </h2>
  <hr>
  <ol type="1" id="ol1">
    <li>
      Presentaci&oacute;n
    </li>
    <li>
      Razas
      <ul id="ul1">
        <li>
          <a href="Razas/Humanos.html" target="miIframe">Humanos</a> 
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="Razas/Elfos.html" target="miIframe">Elfos</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="Razas/Ogros.html" target="miIframe">Ogros</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="Razas/Enanos.html" target="miIframe">Enanos</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      Zonas
      <ul id="ul2">
        <li>
          <a href="Zonas/Rios.html" target="miIframe">R&iacute;os</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="Zonas/Bosques.html" target="miIframe">Bosques</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="Zonas/Ciudades.html" target="miIframe">Ciudades</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="Zonas/Monta%C3%B1as.html" target="miIframe">Montañas</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="Zonas/Sub.html" target="miIframe">Reino Submarino</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="Zonas/Cielo.html" target="miIframe">Reino del Cielo</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="Tablas.html" target="miIframe">Estad&iacute;sticas y Tablas</a>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
<div id="contenido">
  <iframe name="miIframe" width="100%" height="100%" src="Pagina%20titulo.html"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Por que no intentas con jQuery, existe una función llamada .load(), que tiene la siguiente sintaxis:

**.load( url [, data] [, callback(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)] )**

1. **url**: es la cadena que contiene la url a cargar. (obligatoria).
2. **data**: parametros que podemos pasar para ser tratados por el destino de la url. (opcional).
3. **callback**: función invocada después de procesarse la url. (opcional).

Este es un ejemplo de uso:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script>

            $( document ).ready(function() {
                //Se abre por default una página en el div content
                $("#content").load('principal.html', function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){
                    //En caso de que se haya cargado correctamente se manda un mensaje al log
                    if(statusTxt == "success")
                            console.log("Contenido abierto exitosamente");
                    //En caso de que se haya un error se manda el estatus y la descripción de este
                    if(statusTxt == "error")
                            console.log("Ocurrió un error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
                });
                //función que se manda llamar cada vez que se da click en cada liga de div menu     
                $('#menu a').click(function(evt) {
                    //Evita que la página se redireccione a la página que se encuentra en el atributo href.
                    evt.preventDefault();
                    //se obtiene el atributo href
                    var pagina = $(this).attr('href');
                    //se manda llamar la función load para el div content
                    $("#content").load(pagina, function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){
                        //En caso de que se haya cargado correctamente se manda un mensaje al log
                        if(statusTxt == "success")
                            console.log("Contenido abierto exitosamente");
                        //En caso de que se haya un error se manda el estatus y la descripción de este
                        if(statusTxt == "error")
                            console.log("Ocurrió un error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
                    });

                });
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "menu"> 
            <li>    
                <a href="humanos.html">Humanos</a> 
            </li>
            <li>    
                <a href="elfos.html">Elfos</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="ogros.html">Ogros</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="enanos.html">Enanos</a>
            </li>
        </div>  
        <div id="content"></div>    
    </body>
</html>
```